# Узнать год рождения по возрасту Carbon

Tags: laravel, carbon

знаю что в Carbon можно узнать возраст по дате рождения

```
$dateOfBirth = '1994-07-02';

$years = \Carbon::parse($dateOfBirth)->age;
```

А можно ли узнать год рождения по возрасту ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ отнять возраст от текущей даты

```
$carbon = now()->subYear($age);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$year = Carbon::now()->subYear($age)->year;
```